# Get title opening windows and close with specific title?

Tags: windows, vbscript

How can I close a window with a specific title in Windows XP base using VBscript?

Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`SendKeys`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83.aspx) method to send the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut to the window you wish to close. This window must be active at the moment, so you also need to call [`AppActivate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wzcddbek.aspx) right before `SendKeys`.

Basically, you'll need something like this:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
oShell.AppActivate "Untitled - Notepad"
oShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
```

You may want to add checks and small delays to make your script more foolproof:

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
If oShell.AppActivate("Untitled - Notepad") Then
   WScript.Sleep 500
   oShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
End If
```

---

***Edit:*** (An answer to your comment/question about VBScript resources.)

I've compiled some links to VBScript websites and resource pages that I hope they will be helpful:

**Learning**

- [Scripting: Your First Steps](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd940112.aspx)
- [Sesame Script](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd772284.aspx) ([CHM download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=FF973FBE-9382-4E4C-80DE-E7DE14FD83E6))
- [VBScript Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/default.asp) on W3Schools (note: this tutorial is oriented on browser scripting, not desktop scripting)

**References**

- [VBScript User's Guide & Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t0aew7h6.aspx) in MSDN ([CHM donwload](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=01592C48-207D-4BE1-8A76-1C4099D7BBB9))

**Other resources**

- [TechNet Script Center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/default.aspx) ([CHM download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=75cca21a-53b9-4949-9b62-a8fc7926e914))
- [TechNet Script Repository](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/) ([CHM download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=b4cb2678-dafb-4e30-b2da-b8814fe2da5a))
- [Hey, Scripting Guy! blog](http://blogs.technet.com/heyscriptingguy/) ([CHM arvhive](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5f5e0bda-923a-4744-8289-afb73f6a5ed8))
- [Rob van der Woude's Scripting Pages](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/wsh.php)
- Also, check out [VBScript questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vbscript) here on Stack Overflow

As for VBScript resources in Russian, check out [script-coding.info](http://script-coding.info/) and [Серый форум](http://forum.script-coding.info/) — there're lots of useful and interesting examples. Also, take a look at the [this thread](http://forum.script-coding.info/viewtopic.php?id=10), which contains links to many VBScript resources, including those in Russian.

Comment: Great it works!!! Thank you !!!Can you tell literature useful for vbscript or english or russian ;)

Comment: One questions how it will be on Windows 7 ?
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
If oShell.AppActivate("Untitled - Notepad") Then
   WScript.Sleep 500
   oShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
End If

this not work on windows 7 ((((

Answer (score 0):

**Posting this answer for anyone who is still stuck on trying to close the WScript.Shell Object after creating it and not able to find a solution. I tried the above solution and it cause MSWord 2016 to crash, don't know the reason
    My Vb Script :**

```
        Dim wsh As Object
        Set wsh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell", vbNothing)
        wsh.Run "cmd.exe /C pause"
        wsh.Run "taskkill /F /IM cmd.exe"
```