# What is the equivalent of window.opener without opening a new window?

Tags: javascript

A library I am using gets a reference to the main window by adding this script to a popup window:
    var winMain=window.opener;

This script lets the popup window access global variables from the window that opened it. Example:

```
<select name=MonthSelector onChange="javascript:winMain.Cal.SwitchMth(this.selectedIndex);winMain.RenderCal();">
```

However this leaves me in an awkward position if I try to call some of these variables without opening a new window. (For instance, if I try to embed one of the calendars inside a div instead of a new window.)

```
  onChange="javascript:Cal.SwitchMth(this.selectedIndex);"
```

and

```
  var winMain=window;
  onChange="javascript:winMain.Cal.SwitchMth(this.selectedIndex);"
```

Both don't seem to work.  Is there some way to get the current window's handle as a variable?  Or an I just doing something wrong?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708151/how-to-get-the-main-window-handle-of-a-process-using-jscript) appears similar to mine, but the answers don't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change it to

```
var winMain = window.opener || window;
```

It says is there is no window.opener, use window.

Comment: That worked!  I feel rather foolish for not noticing that I misspelled winMain.

Answer (score 0):

A *window.open* equivalent is below

```
var w = window.open('', '', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
w.document.write('Content goes here');
w.document.close();
```

Use it according to your need.